# How to increase the font size of x and y axis label, when cex.lab did not work in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have the following graph:

[image]

What I want to do is to increase the font size for X-axis and y-axis label.

To do that I use `cex.lab` for this line of code:

```
plot(datax2$tau_bar,datax2$anshit_norm,type="b",lty=4,col=mypalette[1],cex.lab=2.5,cex=1.5,lwd=3,main="",pch=8,font.main=1,xlab="",ylab="",xlim=c(0.01,0.4),ylim=c(0,1))
```

But somehow the font size didn't change at all?
What's the way to do that?

This is the complete code that generate the figures:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(RColorBrewer);
library(gregmisc);

dat<-read.table("http://dpaste.com/1583393/plain/", header=F);
some_thres <- 38; 
final_plot <- paste("Output.pdf",sep="");


# Renaming Variables
dat<-rename.vars(dat,c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9","V10","V11"),c("cov","ed","err","tau_bar","true_c","true_t","true","false","ans_c","ans_t","ans_hit"));

cv       <- c(35,50,100,200,300);
edis     <- c(4,6);
errorp   <- c(0,1,2,4);


# For line color
mypalette       <- brewer.pal(10,"RdGy") 
col_plot        <- c(mypalette[2],mypalette[10]); 

ltyp <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8)
pcht <- c(0,1,2);

pdf(final_plot,width=30,height=6)

#--------------------------------------------------
# Plotting 
#-------------------------------------------------- 
op <- par(mfrow=c(1,5),   xaxs="i", yaxs="i")

for (i in 1:length(cv)) {
        for (k in 1:length(edis)){

            datax <- subset(dat,cov==cv[i] & err==errorp[1] & ed==edis[k]  & tau_bar <= 0.4 ,select = c(ed,true,false,tau_bar,ans_hit))
            nofrow <- nrow(datax)

          if (nofrow > 0 ) {
             title <- paste(cv[i],"lim",sep="");

              if(cv[i] == 50 & (edis[k]==0 || edis[k]==4)) next;



              false_max <- max(datax$false);
              true_max <- max(datax$true);
              false_min <- min(datax$false);
              true_min <- min(datax$true);

              max_y <- max(false_max,true_max);

             anshit_norm <- datax$ans_hit/some_thres

             fptp_ratio <- (datax$false)/(datax$true + datax$false);
             precision <- 1 - fptp_ratio;

             datax2 <- cbind(datax,anshit_norm,fptp_ratio,precision);

              plot(datax2$tau_bar,datax2$anshit_norm,type="b",lty=4,col=mypalette[1],cex.lab=2.5,cex=1.5,lwd=3,main="",pch=8,font.main=1,xlab="",ylab="",xlim=c(0.01,0.4),ylim=c(0,1))
              mtext(title,side=3,line=2.0,cex=2);
              mtext(expression(paste(some," threshold")),side=1,line=4,cex=1.5)

          }


            for (j in 1:length(errorp)){
                datax_sub <- subset(dat,cov==cv[i] & err==errorp[j] & ed==edis[k]  & tau_bar <= 0.4 ,select = c(ed,true,false,tau_bar,ans_hit))
                nofrow_sub <- nrow(datax_sub)
                if (nofrow_sub > 0 ) {
                    if(cv[i] == 50 & (edis[k]==0 || edis[k]==4)) next;


                    false_max_sub <- max(datax_sub$false);
                    true_max_sub <- max(datax_sub$true);
                    false_min_sub <- min(datax_sub$false);
                    true_min_sub <- min(datax_sub$true);

                    max_y_sub <- max(false_max_sub,true_max_sub);

                    anshit_norm_sub <- datax_sub$ans_hit/some_thres

                    fptp_ratio_sub <- (datax_sub$false)/(datax_sub$true + datax_sub$false);
                    precision_sub <- 1 - fptp_ratio_sub;


                    datax2_sub <- cbind(datax_sub,anshit_norm_sub,fptp_ratio_sub,precision_sub);
                    lines(datax2_sub$tau_bar,datax2_sub$anshit_norm,col=mypalette[j],type="b",cex=1.5,lty=4,pch=8,lwd=3);
                    lines(datax2_sub$tau_bar,datax2_sub$precision,col=mypalette[j],type="b",cex=1.5,lty=1,pch=1,lwd=3);

                  }
            }

    }
}



dev.off();
```

Comment: Do you look for `cex.axis`? e.g. `plot(1:10, cex.axis=2.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `cex.axis` instead of `cex.lab`. `cex.lab` increases the font size of the labels and `cex.axis` the size of the axis' tick labels.

Try:

```
plot(1:10, cex.axis=2.5)
```

For a complete overview about all `cex.*` have a look at `?par`.